# Delphi FormKeyDown ALT Key Stuck

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, vcl, keylogger

I have a form with 2 CheckBoxes (1 is for holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - 1 is for holding <kbd>ALT</kbd>).
Both CheckBoxes are disabled so the `KeyDown Event` of the form works properly.
There is also a `TTimer` that synchronizes every 10ms if the <kbd>ALT</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is pressed.

My `timer`:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 CheckBox1.Checked := ALTDOWN;  // ALTDOWN IS GLOBAL
 CheckBox2.Checked := CTRLDOWN; // CTRLDOWN IS GLOBAL
end;
```

My `KeyDown Event`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
begin
 if Key = VK_MENU then begin
  ALTDOWN := TRUE;
  exit;
 end;
 if Key = VK_CONTROL then begin
  CTRLDOWN := TRUE;
  exit;
 end;
end;
```

My `KeyUP Event`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
begin
 if Key = VK_MENU then begin
  ALTDOWN := FALSE;
  exit;
 end;
 if Key = VK_CONTROL then begin
  CTRLDOWN := FALSE;
  exit;
 end;
end;
```

This works without any problems with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.
But the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key get's stuck sometimes or does not even show up at all.
This happens when I press ONLY the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key (without any other keys in combination).

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to run a timer in that way, then you may as well just call [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 CheckBox1.Checked := GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)<0;
 CheckBox2.Checked := GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0;
end;
```

And just get rid of your `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` event handlers. There's really no point in you trying to keep track of whether the key is up or down when the system already does so.

Your timer interval is quite short. The system won't fire them that frequently anyway. If I recall correctly the timer resolution is typically around 50ms.

Comment: this works. But this would actually block for example the same process if it's open twice?!

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss No, that's not the case. This is the *right* way to do this.

Comment: This works but it works even if the window is not active. Should I add if Self.Active [...] ? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It just works! All you need to do is use the code exactly as it is. The system keeps track of whether or not each key is up or down. `GetAsyncKeyState` provides access to that information.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I wanted to capture the keys ONLY within the form so all I need to add to this is if Self.Active then CheckBox1[...]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That way your app displays the wrong information when it is not the foreground app. The timer is still going to fire. You may as well display the right information. Either the key is up or it is down. Whether or not your app is the foreground app is orthogonal to that.

Comment: The purpose is to synchronize a remote keyboard if the form is active. But your solution is good. GetAsyncKeyState does the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding "Why is that" i believe it is because after you pressed Alt your form is no more active. Active control would be menu, activated by sole-Alt. Either main menu or system menu. That also refers to ur last question, i expect hat after menu is open your form is no more active control, but you may try and test it.

Comment: that's a very good thinking! Altough I have no menu... I will see if the form is still active that way. EDIT: That's not it. The form is still active after I pressed the ALT Key.

Answer (score 1):

Read microsoft documentation when you want to get inside its internal ways (and KeyUp is that)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx

You can see that releasing Alt key is system event and would not be expected in WM_KeyUp. 
Add monitoring of WM_SYSCOMMAND, WM_SYSKEYUP and WM_SYSKEYDOWN as well.

Comment: The `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` fires you the `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` events (posponed to the form when you have `KeyPreview` set to True).

Comment: But probably not WM_SYSCOMMAND

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm not sure how `WM_SYSCOMMAND` relates to the question of whether or not the ALT key is up or down.

Comment: If TS wants to check whether Alt key was released, then WM_SYSCOMMAND would be helpful.

But anyway, if topic starter no more insists on tracking up/down messages and okay with AsyncGetState, then that probably just does not matter. However initially he wasopposing to AsyncGetState and i wanted to show alternate approach.